# can't add the AccountId field in the "Select Opportunity Product Fields to Store in Variable" section - Get Record flow element

Tags: workflow

I'm trying to get all the opportunity line item for one opportunity. I'm using the Get Record flow element. Now how can I add the AccountId field in the *Select Opportunity Product Fields to Store in Variable* section:

[image]

apparently I can't add `Opportunity.AccountId`

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SFDC implicitly will enable you access to parent fields as long as you include the ID of the immediate parent field(s) in the record collection variable. In effect, when the flow is compiled, references to lookup fields in downstream elements (like assignments) are recognized by SFDC and included in the SOQL query generated *behind the scenes* for the `Get Records` element.

I built a trivial flow that illustrates this using a Get Record on Opportunity and showing that I can retrieve the `Opportunity.Account.Name` merely by including the Opportunity.AccountId in the `Get Record` for `Opportunity`

[image]

Here's the details of each element (succinctly depicted by the debug pane) *2 Opportunities in test dataset*

[image]

Comment: Thank you @cropredy for your response, really appreciate your help